# comparing strings of digits with zeros padding

Tags: ruby, csv

Am having an issue in importing strings with the rails csv module `require 'csv'` of digits with zeros padding the number.

The following two queries give different results. The first is considering the input in binary mode,
the second is effecting the proper query.

```
Client.where('original_identifier = ?', 00002000.to_s).first
 SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE (original_identifier = '1024')

Client.where('original_identifier = ?', "00002000").first
 SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE (original_identifier = '00002000')

Client.where('original_identifier = ?', "00001999").first
```

returns an irb error `Invalid octal digit`

However, for the CSV module

```
@client = Client.where('original_identifier = ?', row[1].to_s).first
```

is generating only null results when I expected the behaviour to be as in the second case.

what is the proper ruby syntax then?

Comment: What is cdv module?

Comment: Why binary? What do you mean?

Comment: Is you issue something about `00002000`? How can a binary have the character `2`?

Comment: (just here because he has the same name as me)

Comment: @sawa typo. csv module.  Whatever ruby is doing, it is assuming in the first case that it is handling an octal digit.  [désolé à l'autre moi...]

Answer (score 0):

Passing first to integer, then to string for matching the search data type

```
@client = Client.where('original_identifier = ?', row[1].to_i.to_s).first
```

is a solution.